# Solution to differential equation (guessing a solution)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I'm having issues trying to solve this differential equation

$x''(t)\ + \ x(t) \ = \ \frac{1}{6} \cdot \cos^3(t),\ x(0)=0 \ ,\ x'(0)=0$

I've been trying to convert $\frac{1}{6} \cdot \cos^3(t)$ to $\frac{1}{48} \cdot (e^{it}+e^{-it})^3$ and then guessing a solution in the form $A\cdot(e^{it}+e^{-it})^3$ but that doesn't work.

I then tried to guess a solution in the form $A\cdot t\cdot(e^{it}+e^{-it})^3$ but it does not seem to work either...

I know the solution to the differential equation is $x(t)=\frac{1}{192} \cdot \cos(t)\ -\frac{1}{192} \cdot \cos(3t) \ +\frac{1}{16}\cdot t\cdot \sin(t)$

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Replace $\cos^3 (t) $ by

$$\frac {(e^{it}+e^{-it})^3}{8}=$$

$$\frac {1}{8}(2\cos (3t)+6\cos (t)) $$

and use superposition principle.

The general solution will have the form
$$y_g=y_h+y_1+y_2$$
with
$$y_h=A\cos (t)+B\sin (t) $$
$$y_1=C\cos (3t)+D\sin (3t) $$
and
$$y_2=t (E\cos(t)+F\sin (t)) $$

Comment: Thanks, it helped a bit! But I'm not sure how to get the solution still, because it seems like every constant is 0 if I make use of the boundary values...